# asp core web api http post is null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, webapi

I created a webapi by looking at the ms basic documentation.

[ms Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-the-todocontext-database-context)

it was work
[todoitems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nC7ud.png)

Besides todoitems I
Because I wanted to use it in the form of Avatar Chart
Insert the model Avatarchart, create Avatarchartcontext, and make the controller as a scaffold.

[solution view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqL50.png)

However, when I tried to receive data as a post, the data always came in null.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaLjs.png)

[null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ5dH.png)

this is code

```
[Route("api/AvatarCharts")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AvatarChartsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly AvatarChartContext _context;

        public AvatarChartsController(AvatarChartContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/AvatarCharts
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<AvatarChart>>> GetAvatarCharts()
        {
            return await _context.AvatarCharts.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/AvatarCharts/5
        [HttpGet("{modelId}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<AvatarChart>> GetAvatarChart(long modelId)
        {
            var avatarChart = await _context.AvatarCharts.FindAsync(modelId);

            if (avatarChart == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return avatarChart;
        }

        // PUT: api/AvatarCharts/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
        [HttpPut("{modelId}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutAvatarChart(long modelId, AvatarChart avatarChart)
        {
            if (modelId != avatarChart.modelId)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(avatarChart).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!AvatarChartExists(modelId))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/AvatarCharts
        // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<AvatarChart>> PostAvatarChart( AvatarChart avatarChart)
        {
            _context.AvatarCharts.Add(avatarChart);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetAvatarChart", new { modelId = avatarChart.modelId }, avatarChart);
        }

        // DELETE: api/AvatarCharts/5
        [HttpDelete("{modelId}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteAvatarChart(long modelId)
        {
            var avatarChart = await _context.AvatarCharts.FindAsync(modelId);
            if (avatarChart == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.AvatarCharts.Remove(avatarChart);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return NoContent();
        }

        private bool AvatarChartExists(long modelId)
        {
            return _context.AvatarCharts.Any(e => e.modelId == modelId);
        }
    }
```

```
 public class AvatarChartContext :DbContext
    {
        public AvatarChartContext(DbContextOptions<AvatarChartContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<AvatarChart> AvatarCharts { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<AvatarChart>().HasKey(c => c.modelId);

            
        }
    }
```

```
public class AvatarChart
    {
        [Key]
        public long modelId;
        public string colorCode;
        public long dateTime;        //ex 20210101130000
        public string name;
        public string diagnose;

    }
```

[swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfK6d.png)

add postgressql db[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B35L1.png)

Comment: https://github.com/jinsw1081/.net-core-postgre-restful-api-migration/tree/StackoverFlow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

You missed the {get; set;}.

```
public class AvatarChart
{
    [Key]
    public long modelId {get; set;}
    public string colorCode {get; set;}
    public long dateTime {get; set;}        //ex 20210101130000
    public string name {get; set;}
    public string diagnose {get; set;}

}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering
   i did that it was not work error is same 
and why todoitems post is work?

Comment: @MasterJung, you should add {get; set;} to your property.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make these changes and tell me what value is being returned on the variable result. Also, can you validate your ModelState first?
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> PostAvatarChart( AvatarChart avatarChart)
{

```
        await _context.AvatarCharts.AddAsync(avatarChart);
        var result = await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;

        return CreatedAtAction("GetAvatarChart", new { modelId = avatarChart.modelId }, avatarChart);
    }
```

Comment: result is false 
 public async Task<ActionResult<AvatarChart>> PostAvatarChart([FromBody] AvatarChart avatarChart)
avatarChart value is null

Comment: Since he is using the ApiController attribute on top of the Controller, I think [FromBody] should have been handled automatically. I don't explicitly write [FromBody].

Comment: @MasterJung yeah, I suddenly find it's a api project, there is no need [FromBody].

Comment: JSON should have also worked fine, I don't know why the form's data is not being sent.

Comment: @mj1313 Could you please debug your code right from the start or post your project on some repo public? there must have been some missing.

Comment: @shayarshrestha add comment git repo open